# How to install extra bin files when `npm install` is given `-g` flag?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there some way to install only part of a NodeJS project when run via `npm install`, but to install additional features when `npm install -g` is used?

I have a library with a command-line interface, however the CLI is not useful to any downstream projects using my library.  So when those projects pull in my library, I don't want them to pull down dependencies like `chalk` that are only used for the CLI they will never touch.

However if an end user decides to install my library globally on their system with `npm install -g` then I want the CLI installed, and via the `bin` section in `package.json`, placed in their path so they can run it like any other program.

I can't work out how to do this without splitting the CLI into a separate package.  The options I have investigated are:

- Put the CLI dependencies as `devDependencies`.  This prevents `chalk` etc. from being installed in downstream projects, but the drawback here is that the user must `npm install -g` in development mode, which means they get the test framework and linting tools installed as well even though they will never use them.
- Put the CLI as a separate NodeJS package/module.  The drawback here is that it makes testing difficult (as often the CLI and library are modified at the same time and used for testing new features), and developers wanting to contribute to the library will have to stuff around with linking the two packages so although it would work, it's less than ideal from a workflow perspective.
- Put the CLI in a folder inside the main package, and create another `package.json` in there just for the CLI, pulling in the main project via `npm install ..`.  This works until you get to the install point, when you realise that there is no way to install the CLI once the package has been published.  `npm install @my/library` will only install from the `package.json` in the project root, there's no way to say "oh also install the package in the `cli` subdirectory too."

Ideally what I would like is this:

- `npm install @my/library` - run by a developer wanting to use the library in their project.  Adds the library only to their project's dependencies, ignores both CLI and any dependencies the CLI needs.
- `npm install -g @my/library` - run by an end-user, installs library and CLI globally on their system, including the CLI dependencies, and adds the CLI to the user's path via the `package.json` `bin` section.
- `npm install --dev` - used by developer contributing to the library to install the test framework so they can run the unit tests before submitting their code for inclusion.
- Not having to split the CLI into a separate project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came up with a workaround.

I put the CLI back to development-only (with its requirements in `devDependencies` so it could be used by local devs, but they wouldn't get pulled in to downstream projects using the library).  I then created another package for the CLI, but all it was is a `package.json` file and nothing else.

What this package does is depend on the main library, plus only the dependencies needed by the CLI.  Then it uses the `bin` section to point to the CLI **inside the main library**, so no code is needed in this package - it is literally just one file.  Like so:

```
{
  "name": "@my/library-cli",  // new module to install the CLI
  "bin": {
    "myprog": "./node_modules/@my/library/bin/myprog.js"  // the command is inside the dependency
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@my/library": "*",       // require the library itself where the CLI code sits
    "command-line-args": "*"  // dependency needed by the CLI
  }
}
```

The only drawback with this is that this new package's `dependencies` need to be kept in sync with the main library's `devDependencies` (at least the deps required by the CLI) but as they won't change often in my case I can live with that.

I did try the postinstall hook as @Trott suggested but it didn't seem to work:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "[ $npm_config_global == 'true' ] && (cd cli && npm install -g)"
}
```

For some reason it was incredibly slow and seemed to get stuck in a loop, trying and failing to install over and over.  I'm also not sure it would've respected being launched via a command like `npm install -g --prefix /my/install/folder` as that non-standard prefix may not get passed through to the child `npm` process.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to install only part of a NodeJS project when run via `npm install`, but to install additional features when `npm install -g` is used?

You can write a [`postinstall` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) that uses [`is-globally-installed`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-installed-globally) (or another similar package) to check if the module is installed globally, and then run whatever is appropriate to install the CLI (perhaps `npm install -g` for a separate package that just has the CLI).

Comment: This is a great idea, but how do I pass `npm` parameters though?  For example if the original caller wrote `npm install -g --prefix /my/install/folder` is there an easy way to ensure those extra parameters get passed through to the child `npm` process?  I know the `make` program has the special `$(MAKE)` variable which expands to the command with all the extra parameters set but I can't see if `npm` has an equivalent.  I'm assuming it needs one because when I tried running `cd cli && npm install -g` inside the `post-install` script it froze.